# Using jQuery to find the selected value between the td and the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

The function below is used to find the reference number then compare it, then if the corresponding value is found the cell values are modified according to the input boxes. This works great, however, how do I go about modifying the existing function below to capture the value between the

```
<td><div>this value here</div></td>
```

Here is the Javascript in question:

```
function changeit() {
    var valueToFind = $('#number').val();
    $('#data > tbody> tr').each(function(index) {
        console.log(index);
        var firstTd = $(this).find('td:first');
        if ($(firstTd).text() == valueToFind) {
            console.log("found: " + index + ":" + valueToFind);
            $(this).find('td:eq(1)').text($('#item').val());
            $(this).find('td:eq(2)').text($('#color').val());
        }
    })
}
```

Here is the HTML Markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us">

</head>

<body>

    Number:*
    <input type="text" id="number">
    <br> Items:
    <input type="text" id="item">
    <br> Color:
    <input type="text" id="color">
    <br>

    <br>

    <input type="button" onclick="changeit()" value="save">

    <br>

    <table id="data" style="width: 100%" cellspacing="1" class="style1">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div><b>Number*</b></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div><b>items</b></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div><b>Colors</b></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div>
                        <div>123</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div>Boats</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div>red</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div>456</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div>Vehicles</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div>blue</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div>789</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div>Motorcycles</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div>green</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: cant you just change var firstTd = $(this).find('td:first'); to var firstTd = $(this).find('td:first div'); ?

Comment: ok post that as an answer, and I will accept!

Comment: or you can also do this. if ($(firstTd).text() == valueToFind) to  if ($("div",$(firstTd)).text() == valueToFind)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
 var firstTd = $(this).find('td:first');
```

to

```
 var firstTd = $(this).find('td:first div');
```